# TCP connection not arriving at process depending on source interface

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp

I have a strange case where a TCP connection seems to not arrive on the listening socket, depending on the source interface.

The context: I'm trying to configure the Zabbix agent on a specific host (AGENTIP). This involves the Zabbix server (SERVERIP) connecting to AGENTIP:10050 (tcp). The tcp connection seems to work when running `telnet AGENTIP 10050` on the AGENTIP host. However, whenever I do the same command from the Zabbix server, the connection doesn't arrive at the zabbix-agent2 process. I've established this with strace. `tcpdump` shows the packets are almost identical:

Working (AGENTIP connects to AGENTIP:10050):

```
12:47:09.368585 lo    In  IP AGENTIP.36870  > AGENTIP.10050: Flags [S], seq 2114873310, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 973877732  ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

[pid 2456233] accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(36870), sin_addr=inet_addr("AGENTIP")}, [112 => 16], SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 11
```

Not working (SERVERIP connects to AGENTIP:10050):

```
12:48:05.298526 eth0  In  IP SERVERIP.41580 > AGENTIP.10050: Flags [S], seq 2687217389, win 64240, options [mss 1460 ,sackOK,TS val 2072822359 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

(nothing)
```

The only significant difference I see is the interface the packets arrive on. I'm not aware of a way a process can choose which packets it wants based on that though.

I've disabled the firewall (ufw) on AGENTIP. I've tried to force the process to listen on 0.0.0.0 as well as on AGENTIP, but the behavior stays the same.

I'm not aware of an extra step between the tcp connection arriving (according to tcpdump) and the opened socket which strace gives information about. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `The only significant difference I see is the interface the packets arrive on. I'm not aware of a way a process can choose which packets it wants based on that` It's a loopback interface. I would expect local traffic to use loopback. If you try from any other host it should be the Ethernet interface.

Comment: Correct, when trying from another host the packets arrive on the eth0 interface. But they don't seem to hit the socket opened bij the process I described.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved by rebooting the server during a downtime window.